# selenium webdriver find_element_by_xpath

Tags: selenium

I am trying to click on the accept button using xpath in [www.simulator.betfair.com](http://www.simulator.betfair.com) but it keeps giving me the error down below

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]"}
> (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.85)

Any ideas? this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = r"C:\Users\salde\Desktop\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=url)

driver.get('https://simulator.betfair.com/')

cookies = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')
cookies.click()
```

Comment: I am sorry i ment i am trying to click the button, not displaying the text.

Comment: i have tried the WebDriverWait module by adding the following code, but still no luck.

Comment: ``` url = r"C:\Users\salde\Desktop\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe" ```

``` driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=url) ```

driver.get('https://simulator.betfair.com/')


```element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]'))
)```
```element.click()```

Comment: The problem is that we (at least me) can't open the link you provided..

Comment: Well site that mentioned in the post is unreachable. Could you please add the html code of the button, Do not add the screenshot.

Comment: <button id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler" tabindex="0">Accept all cookies</button>

Comment: https://simulator.betfair.com/

Comment: now with the above code it will not give me any error but it will simply not click the button as i was expected